# android - enter multiple string values to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I have an app in android that handles reporting about classes taken.

I have a edittext that is for entering the teacher's name, but there is a possibilty that there are more then one teacher.

I want to put all the names in the same edittext, similar to how its on gamil -

where you send a mail in gmail, you can enter multiple addresses (multiple values).

**Best would be to have an autocompletetextview that will enalbe multiple names (values) in it, and the user can choose between pre-defined name options.**

any ideas??

thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is something you need.

You can use MultiAutoCompleteTextView from android widgets.

but here is more customizable version of it check this link [TokenAutoCompleteTextView](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete)

It is same like gmail bubbles.It extends MultiAutoCompleteTextView from android widgets.

Hope it will help.Thanks